# how to pxselector pxseach with condition in acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello im working on a project where i have to put a put condition on my selector i know how to pxselect but im now doing it on a dac

```
 #region UsrMarginCodess
        [PXDBString]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Margincode")]
        [PXSelector(
            typeof(Search<Margincode.code, Where<Margincode.show, Equal<true>>>),
                typeof(Margincode.code))]
        public virtual string UsrMarginCodess { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrMarginCodess : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrMarginCodess> { }
        #endregion
```

here is my code i want to select margincode where the show is true
i just want to show the fields that are true on my selector
[image]

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your condition to  `Equal<True>`

Answer (score 0):

Each grid should have a view inside the graph. If you wanna show only records with `Margincode.show == true` in your grid - you just need to add a condition to the view declaration. For example

```
public PXSelect<Margincode, 
    Where<Margincode.show, Equal<True>>> MarginCodes;
```

You can also use a standard Acumatica filter mechanism to filter records by some condition. See "Release AP Documents" (AP501000) screen as an example.
[image]

Comment: what if its a selector on opportunities and i want to make a selector out of it

Comment: what do you mean? you already have the right condition in your selector Search<Margincode.code, Where<Margincode.show, Equal<True>>> and you can use it on any DAC entity. It will create a separate DB request and select Margincode records with show = true